# Core advantages of exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I noticed in my company that people seem to excessivly use exceptions. 
Example of a use case:

```
void check(size_t s, int64_t i) 
{
  if (i < 0 || size_t(i) >= s)
  {
    stringstream st;
    st << "bar";
    throw Exception (st.str());
  }
}

foo & operator() (size_t i) const
{
    // access out of range?
    check(s,i);
    return data[i]; 
}
```

I my opinion, the example above should be replaced with an assert, because the program would end up in UB. (It is not a system which have to continue to work to keep people alive and/or uses sensor input).

- Handling exceptions in threads is tricky
- Library specific (non-standard) exception definitions require special handling in the program

  - Using several libraries with their own exceptions types..
  - You have to check in some cases dozens of potential exceptions..

What do I miss about exceptions? What are e.g. core advantages? Why should the error handling be split into program and library?

Comment: [The standard `assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is a *macro*, and it will expand do nothing if the macro `NDEBUG` is defined (which is common in release builds). Assertions are more for testing and debugging, not for general error checking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and it pressed enter prematurely apparently

Comment: @Borgleader Yes it did. Good thing comments can be edited. :)

Comment: You can recover from an exception unlike from an assert/abort, and they do correct destructor-respecting unwinding without your having to check return codes.

Comment: *would end up in UB* It doesn't follow from posted code. *Exceptions make the code look like a mess* Really? Got an example? *They bloat error handling* Really? How? *you have to check them in the program* Of course you have --- at one place or at a limited number of places, as opposed to returning error codes which you have to check **at every call**. *You have to check in some cases dozens of potential exceptions* What is your alternative? Not checking for errors? *Handling exceptions in threads is tricky* Nope. All in all, you have an opinionated rant, not a technical question.

Comment: @n.m. I think it is very clear what I meant with bloating error handling.

Comment: Personally I'd be more concerned about your `const` function returning a non-`const` reference, and the use of `int64_t` with all the type conversions that creates.

Comment: @dgrat I don’t; exceptions are designed to improve handling of exceptional cases. "Bloat" is subjective; without understanding why you think it’s "bloat" compared to the alternatives it’s difficult to provide opinions or alternatives. "Assert" isn’t for general exception handling that won’t occur in normal use.

Comment: *I think it is very clear what I meant*  I've got not a slightest idea what you meant. Can you show a piece of code that uses exceptions, and then a piece of code that doesn't and offers similar functionality? Then we can compare what's more bloated.

Comment: One factor to consider when comparing `throw` to `std::abort`: what will happen from the user's point of view if the program does abort in production?

Comment: I live in a world where centrlized exeption handling does not exist and some libraries create dozens of exception types in cases where UB is induced. However, the point about stack unwinding seems interesting.

Comment: @n.m. I already gave an example. The Exception there is btw also not the standard one :D

Comment: btw. there is of course UB if i is bigger s. This is the reason there was an exception in the first place.

Comment: The OP is asking for *core* advantages which, for me, takes the "primarily" out of "primarily opinion based". Voted to reopen. There's enough about *core* for some absolutes here. It's also a pity that no answer has yet mentioned the pitfalls of using exceptions across ABIs; fail codes do have their place.

Comment: @Bathsheba: There's more than three questions, some are unanswerable like "What do I miss about …". Going even deeper into implementation details as you propose would increase the confusion. And there is also no need to go to this level. (why do C or C++ people always go to the implementation, I've nnever seen Python or Java features been discussed like "but you can implement them like …" **without true need**)

Comment: Maybe the issue at your company isn't using exceptions too much, but using them wrong.  Throwing anything not publicly derived from `std::exception` is a horrible idea, and catch handlers should be uncommon and general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To adress your concerns:

> Exceptions make the code look like a mess

If you compare code with proper exception handling to code that simply gives up and dies (or worse, continues into UB) when encountering an unexpected situation, then yes. But that's not a fair comparison. Whether the effort saved by resorting to the second option is worth it is for you and your company to decide.

> If you create an exception in a library you have to check them in the program, otherwise they are useless

Again, what is the alternative? Checking error codes is *way* more bloat. Is it preferred if the library crashes your program instead?

> You have to check in some cases dozens of potential exceptions..

This is easy to avoid if the exceptions are polymorphic (like the standard ones). If your library throws 20 different exceptions that do not share a common base class, please complain to the library vendor. Otherwise, *you* can choose whether you want to generically handle them together ("Problem in library: " followed by error code/message) or actually filter them.

> Handling exceptions in threads is tricky

Not any more than threads themselves are tricky. There are situations where you have to be careful or where premade algorithms will not deal with them well, but that's threading for you.

> What do I miss about exceptions?

The core idea of exceptions is that you can *safely* resume normal/other operations upon encountering them. Exceptions make it easy to write code that will not leak memory, enter UB or the like when a recoverable error happens.

And even if you decide that all errors are unrecoverable and do no exception handling, unhandled exceptions will 1. provide a stack trace to the location of the error and 2. yield some hopefully useful debug messages. Asserts may do that, but are generally disabled in release builds so you would have 0 protection against running into UB there.

Comment: I like this answer. However, the counter argument with the error codes sounds negative. E.g. Qt is using them with success and they have their advantages too. On the other hand if the program should just go on, exeptions may have their advantage over them. The stl makes use of them with great success aswell :D

Answer (score 5):

Some advantages of exceptions:

- they can be caught and the error possibly handled without program termination
- they guarantee stack unwinding - `assert` simply calls `abort`
- they allow error handling to be centralised
- they can possibly carry more information about the error than a simple string

Comment: `assert` can also cause subtle differences between NDEBUG and non-NDEBUG builds; it's all too easy to have an assert call that has side-effects.

Comment: exceptions throws are sometimes also encapsulated between macros. This point is invalid.

Comment: @dgrat: Not in my firm it ain't. Not inheriting from `std::exception` is also pretty reprehensible, unless you have a good reason not to. Further study also reveals an out-of-the-box out of range exception defined in the C++ standard library, so why roll your own? The moral of the story is that you can't learn C++ from the gutter.

Comment: Good to know :)